# Simple Time Series Analysis

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we have collected a set of data points $\{a_{t}\}$ at time $t = 1, 2, ..., t', ..., n$. Each data point consists of the following attributes: `Average Citizen Income`, `GDP`, `Education Expense`.

At time $t'$, the government introduces certain policies, and I am interested in testing whether these policies has effect on `Average Citizen Income`.

Ideally, I want to introduce an extra dummy attribute `Policy` for these data points, in which the data points collected before time $t'$ will take `Policy = 0`, and the remaining data points will take `Policy = 1`. Then I will regress `Average Citizen Income` on `GDP`, `Education Expense`, and `Policy`, and test whether the coefficient of `Policy` is 0.

However, in this case the data points have time dependence, so I don't think I can directly adapt this approach. I wonder whether there are similar approaches (or alternative approaches) for testing whether *the introduction of the government policies has effect on the average citizen income*.

Comment: Check the local level model with explanatory variables and intervention (policy). There is a UK seatbelt policy example by Koopman which is quite similar to what you are trying to do. They look at the death rate before and after the seatbelt law, with some additional variables like cost of fuel.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Thank you very much for the reference, I will certainly look into that. :)

Comment: http://www.listinet.com/bibliografia-comuna/Cdu339-C8E1.pdf Chapter 6.